# Advanced filtering in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I have a pcap file where I have a proprietary header from 13th byte to 110th byte. Is there a way I can strip of this portion from every packet in pcap file and then use wireshark to display the remaining packet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for certain that *every* packet has the same proprietary header in the same location and is the same size, then you can use [`editcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html) to remove the unwanted bytes.  For example:

```
editcap -C 12:98 file_with_prop_hdr.pcap file_without_prop_hdr.pcap
```

Comment: Thanks it really helped me